# How do I disable checkbox in parent when all its childnodes are checked

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I want to disable user for changing state of check box in TreeView after all nodes and childnodes are checke. This is the way how I check all items in treeview:

```
private void CheckItems()
{
   foreach (TreeNode node in tvSastavnica.Nodes)
   {
     node.Checked = true;
     CheckChildren(node, true);
   }
}

private void CheckChildren(TreeNode rootNode, bool isChecked)
{
    foreach (TreeNode node in rootNode.Nodes)
    {
      CheckChildren(node, isChecked);
      node.Checked = isChecked;
    }
 }
```

Now I want to grey or somehow lock checkboxes to prevent changing state. Is it possible?

Comment: set your treeview's Enabled property to false ,is this ok?

Comment: Unfortunately no because than I cant scroll or sarch treeview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the **BeforeCheck** and **AfterCheck** events:

```
private void tvSastavnica_BeforeCheck(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Or:

```
private void tvSastavnica_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```